# How should I add Hindi language pack in Magento1.9 community edition? Or it need to create

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, language

I want to add the Hindi as language for store view which is local language in India.

Please can anyone suggest me how should i proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you need to add your Hindi translation files in app/locale/hi_IN.

It's easiest to copy app/locale/en_US/ and start your translations based on these files.

In addition, you need to make sure that your static blocks and pages are translated too unless you only want mostly labels to be translated. There is currently no Hindi translation pack available as of what I know.